# Calling members of outer class from inner class

Tags: java

Here is my class:

```
public class T {
    public  int num = 100;
    private int num2 = -1;

    //inner class
    public static class Inner {
        private int num2 = 250;

        public void method() {
            System.out.println(num2);//calls inner class num
            System.out.println(...);//should print class T num
            System.out.println(...);//should print class T num2
        }   
    }
}
```

How do I make second and third *println* to print *num* and *num2* of class *T*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't - your `Inner` class is not an inner class, it is a static nested class. In other words it lives by itself without a reference to an instance of T.

If you remove the `static` part of your `Inner` declaration, it will be possible:

```
public class Inner {
    private int num2 = 250;

    public void method() {
        System.out.println(num2);//calls inner class num
        System.out.println(num);//should print class T num
        System.out.println(T.this.num2);//should print class T num2
    }   
}
```

Comment: So, a static member class can not access members of the outer class?

Comment: No it can't because a static member is not "linked" to a specific instance. Another way would be to create an instance of `T` in your static nested class - then you could access the non-static members of that instance.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare a nested class `static`, this means that you **dont require the instance of outer  class to create the instance of nested class** in your case `Inner`, so you cannot access the properties of `Outer` class.

But removing `static` **guarantees** that for instance of `Inner` class there will be `Outer` class, so it can access members of `Outer` class.